# PredictionIO Universal Recommender Template Build Error

Tags: predictionio

I was trying to integrate Universal recommender template in prediction IO. Previously I was getting the following following error

ERROR org.apache.predictionio.tools.console.Console$ [Thread-1] - [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.prediction#apache-predictionioo-build;0.10.0-incubating: not found

The I tried the following steps
Deleted project/pio-build.sbt

```
Modified template.json
```

-{"pio": {"version": { "min": "0.9.0" }}}
+{"pio": {"version": { "min": "0.10.0-incubating" }}}

```
Modified build.sbt
```

- "io.prediction"    %% "core"          % pioVersion.value % "provided",
- "org.apache.predictionio"    %% "apache-predictionio-core"   % "0.10.0-incubating" % "provided",
  and get past this error but now I am getting the following error 
  ERROR org.apache.predictionio.tools.console.Console$ [Thread-1] - [error] Type error in expression
  2016-12-08 15:40:57,375 ERROR org.apache.predictionio.tools.console.Console$ [main] - Return code of previous step is 1. Aborting.

I have searched many mailing list ,to find if somone else had same issue but only find 2 posts related to this and unfortunately they couln't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and this version of Universal Recommender solve it: 
https://github.com/actionml/universal-recommender
You might want to follow the guide here to install Mahout 0.13.0 snapshot for this version as well.